# Windows Run dialog and cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, steam

I have a simple problem in which I can launch a program with the `Run` dialog n windows, but not from the CMD (or PowerShell).

The command is `steam://run/<app-id>`

I would like to know how to run the same command from the console. I tried `steam` `steam://` `Steam.exe` but none worked (the last one only opened steam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command window, use the `start` command

```
start steam://run/<app-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really the right forum for this Q, but a quick google leads to Valve's pages that show the command-line options for steam.exe.  I'd recommend a google yourself, but for completeness it looks like steam.exe accepts a **-applaunch** parameter.

Comment: Yes I saw that, the problem is that that needs locating the steam.exe file!